# Is it possible to diff lfs files in git?

Tags: git, git-lfs

When I look at the diff of an lfs file, I just see the oid and size difference.  Is there a way to easily diff the actual file contents?

Comment: When I google "git lfs diff", the first hit is [this](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/440).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From [this post by bk2204](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/440#issuecomment-501007460):

> Another option if you want to have diffs is to run **`git config diff.lfs.textconv cat`**, which will have any files with the `diff=lfs` attribute automatically rendered through Git to show the LFS file instead of the pointer.

---

Sourcetree GUI example:

My diff looked like this:

[image: pre-image]

After running the command, it looks like this:

[image: post-image]

(You might need to re-open Sourcetree for the changes to be applied.)

Comment: This doesn't always work for me. I haven't figured out why yet. When it doesn't work, I use `Sourcetree -> Actions -> External Diff`

Answer (score 0):

There's a script you can use to diff the files, given 2 revisions and the filename. https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2498