# Is it possible to do "git diff --stat" with LFS?

Tags: git, diff, git-lfs

Running `git diff --stat` on LFS tracked files shows output of the pointer.
I'm looking for a way to get a result for the concrete / actual files.
Assume files are text based.

Comment: Whole point of LFS is that git _doesn't_ store diffs, just pointers to whole files. If you wanted to calculate a diff you'd have to retrieve both copies.

Comment: This answer is probably what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58508020/12818462

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Git never stores diffs, always full snapshots.

Comment: @knittl, ...which part of the structure are we talking about? Yes, trees are collections of hashes for full files, but my recollection was that _under that layer_ the content behind the hashes of those blobs were assembled from deltas. (Granted, I got out of the DSCM implementation game about when it became clear that git was going to win in the market, and know a lot less about its underpinnings than, say, Tom Lord's Arch, or Bazaar, or other early competitors).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no, hashes are computed from blobs (full file contents), trees (full directory contents), and commits (meta data: author, date, message, parent commit). Git can use deltas for compression (but doesn't have to). But I think I missed the "not" in your original comment, shame on me and sorry for the noise!

Comment: _nod_, it was compressed storage of blobs as diffs that I was referring to. I'll try to be more careful in the future not to imply that to be mandatory.